# Mysql Case statement Logic

Tags: mysql

```
Complaint_status(id,complaint_id,updated_by,status_type,status_value)

2,0:Open   2,1:Pending   2,2:Closed
```

For example:
Consider a complaint closed 3 times by 3 different user(`111,112,113`),Trying to get `min(id)` of closure,but not closed by 111(112 in this case)

**Another Case**:complaint closed only 1 time by 111 user,its closure time should be `curdate()`

Please suggest what to do in else statement.

```
and cs.id IN(CASE WHEN (select MIN(id) from complaint3_status where complaint_id=c3.id and status_type=2 and status_value = 2) is null 
THEN (select MAX(id) from complaint3_status where complaint_id=c3.id and status_type=2)
ELSE
(
select MIN(id) from complaint3_status where complaint_id=c3.id and status_type=2 and status_value = 2
)
END)
```

Comment: Note that if the above works, it will be too heavy (slow) request in case of many rows.

Comment: @jacob53 does the above works ??

Comment: Yeah..its working fine..trying to implement closed (in else) logic

Comment: @AvinashBabu :above is a part of query only

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.